# JQuery Validate - Submit form only when validation is complete

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I am working on a contact form that uses jquery validate to validate the form to make sure all data entered is correct. Everything is fine expect for when I click the submit button - the validation error messages appear along with a confirmation message saying that the message has been sent. So basically its sending the form although all fields are incomplete.

I only want the form to submit once all fields have been filled out correctly.

I have included my code below...

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

// validate contact form
$(function() {
    $('.contactusform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            telno: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            town: {
                required: true
            },
            device: {
                required: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            },
        
        },

        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your full name."
            },
            telno: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number."
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address."
            },
            town: {
                required: "Please enter your town."
            },
            device: {
                required: "Please select your device."
            },
            message: {
                required: "Please enter your message."
            },
        
        },
    
    })
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.contactusform').validate();

    // grab the submits button ID. do not use <input type="submit"> inside the form. Use a button instead outside the form.
    $("#submit2").click(function()
    {
        // grab the forms ID
        $("#message").submit(function(e)
        {
            // add a loading image in place of your returning outcome
            $("#simple-msg").html("Sending...");

            // serialize/combine all submitted fields into an array
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();

            // set url based of action
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

            // set ajax parameters
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Thanks for your request - we will be in touch soon!</p>');

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Message failed to send. Please try again!</p>');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
            e.unbind();
        });

        $("#message").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
    });

});
</script>
```

Could also someone tell me if it is possible to disable the submit button and clear any data entered into form when submission is successful?

Thanks a lot for all your help in advance.

**UPDATED CODE**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.contactusform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            telno: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            town: {
                required: true
            },
            device: {
                required: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            }, //<---unnecessary, remove it
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your full name."
            },
            telno: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number."
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address."
            },
            town: {
                required: "Please enter your town."
            },
            device: {
                required: "Please select your device."
            },
            message: {
                required: "Please enter your message."
            }, //<---unnecessary, remove it

        },

        //Submit Handler Function
        submitHandler: function (form) {
        // add a loading image in place of your returning outcome
        $("#simple-msg").html("Sending...");
        // serialize/combine all submitted fields into an array
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        // set url based of action
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: formURL,
                data: postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                   $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Thanks for your request - we will be in touch soon!</p>');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Message failed to send. Please try again!</p>');
                }
            });
        }
    }); //<----missing ; in original code
});
</script>
```

**CODE FOR FORM**

```html
<form name='message' id='message' class="contactusform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=admin_url()?>admin-post.php">

<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['message']))
 {
 echo $_SESSION['message'];
 unset($_SESSION['message']);
 }
 ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="foobarid">
    <label>Full Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" required="">
    <label>Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="telno" id="telno">
    <label>Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" required="">
    <label>Town:</label>
    <input type="text" name="town" value="" required="">
    <label>Device:</label>
    <select name="device" value="" required="">
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="Not Sure">Not Sure</option>
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="iPhone 3G">iPhone 3G</option>
        <option value="iPhone 3GS">iPhone 3GS</option>
        <option value="iPhone 4G">iPhone 4G</option>
        <option value="iPhone 4S">iPhone 4S</option>
        <option value="iPhone 5">iPhone 5</option>
        <option value="iPhone 5C">iPhone 5C</option>
        <option value="iPhone 5S">iPhone 5S</option>
        <option value="iPhone 6">iPhone 6</option>
        <option value="iPhone 6 Plus">iPhone 6 Plus</option>
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="MacBook">MacBook</option>
        <option value="MacBook Pro">MacBook Pro</option>
        <option value="MacBook Air">MacBook Air</option>
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="iMac">iMac</option>
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="iPad 1">iPad 1</option>
        <option value="iPad 2">iPad 2</option>
        <option value="iPad 3">iPad 3</option>
        <option value="iPad 4">iPad 4</option>
        <option value="iPad Air">iPad Air</option>
        <option value="iPad Air 2">iPad Air 2</option>
        <option value="iPad Mini 1">iPad Mini 1</option>
        <option value="iPad Mini 2">iPad Mini 2</option>
        <option value="iPad Mini 3">iPad Mini 3</option>
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="iPod Classic">iPod Classic</option>
        <option value="iPod Mini">iPod Mini</option>
        <option value="iPod Nano">iPod Nano</option>
        <option value="iPod Shuffle">iPod Shuffle</option>
        <option value="iPod Touch">iPod Touch</option>
    </select>
    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="4" value="" required=""></textarea>
    <input class="submit2" type='submit' id='submit' value='Send Message' />
</form>
<div id='simple-msg'></div>
```

**CODE FOR PLUGIN**

```html
<?php

if(!defined('WPINC'))
{
die;
}

// create table at plugin activition
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jms_create_db' );
function jms_create_db() 
{
 global $wpdb;
 $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
 $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'contactusform';
 $sql="CREATE TABLE $table_name(
  id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
        telno varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
        town varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
        device varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  message text,
  UNIQUE KEY id (id)
  ) $charset_collate;";
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
 dbDelta( $sql );
}

//adding plugin to admin menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'jms_menu');
function jms_menu() 
{
 add_menu_page(__('Contact Form','jms'), __('Contact Form','jms'),
   'administrator', 'jms-contact-form', 'jms_settings_page', 'dashicons-email');
 function jms_settings_page() 
  {
   global $wpdb;
   $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'contactusform';
   $client_msg = $wpdb->get_results( 
   "
   SELECT *
   FROM $table_name
   "
  );
   require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'settings-page.php');
  }
  
}

function cf_jms()
{
 ob_start();
 require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'form.php');
 return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'jms_contact_form', 'cf_jms' );

//if you want to have both logged in and not logged in users submitting, you have to add both actions!
add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'jms_admin_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_add_foobar', 'jms_admin_add_foobar' );
function jms_admin_add_foobar() {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = array(
        'time'  => current_time('mysql'),
        'name'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['name']),
        'telno'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['telno']),
        'email' => isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? sanitize_email( $_POST['email']) : null,
        'town'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['town']),
        'device'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['device']),
        'message'   => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['message'])
    );

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'contactusform';
    $headers = array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
    // send Email for admin
    wp_mail(
        get_option( 'admin_email' ),
        'Instant Qoute/Callback Form',
        'Time : ' . $data['time'] .
        'Name : ' . $data['name'] .
        'Tel No : ' . $data['telno'] .
        'Email : ' . $data['email'] .
        'Town : ' . $data['town'] .
        'Device : ' . $data['device'] .
        'The message: ' . $data['message'],         
        $headers
    );

    if ( $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $data ) ) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "";
    }
    //redirect back to where user was comming
    wp_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
    //request handlers should die() when they complete their task
}

?>
```

Comment: you need to put that Ajax request in submit handler `submitHandler: function (form) { put Ajax call here and remove that 2nd script and do everything you want to do here inside submit handler}`

Comment: i can suggest you different way. if you agree

Comment: @Joshua, can you share your form's html as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ahmad Baktash Hayeri answer covers almost all the aspect so purpose of this answer is to to use [submitHandler function](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) and when using a plugin why not take advantage of it let it do all the hard work for you.

I suggest totally remove the 2nd script and use `submitHandler function` and handle your Ajax method and all other request in it.

Check following script, you have unnecessary comma's and missing `;`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.contactusform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            telno: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            town: {
                required: true
            },
            device: {
                required: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            }, //<---unnecessary, remove it
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your full name."
            },
            telno: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number."
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address."
            },
            town: {
                required: "Please enter your town."
            },
            device: {
                required: "Please select your device."
            },
            message: {
                required: "Please enter your message."
            }, //<---unnecessary, remove it

        },
        //Submit Handler Function
        submitHandler: function (form) {
        // add a loading image in place of your returning outcome
        $("#simple-msg").html("Sending...");
        // serialize/combine all submitted fields into an array
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        // set url based of action
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: formURL,
                data: postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                   $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Thanks for your request - we will be in touch soon!</p>');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Message failed to send. Please try again!</p>');
                }
            });
        }
    }); //<----missing ; in original code
});
```

Now last to reset form and disable submit button, no idea why you want to disable the submit button,

following can reset the form and disable the submit button

```
$(form)[0].reset();
$('#theSubmitButton').attr("disabled", true);
```

e.g if you want to reset the form and disable button after Ajax success function

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Thanks for your request - we will be in touch soon!</p>');
   $(form)[0].reset();
   $('#theSubmitButton').attr("disabled", true);
},
```

What you don't need anymore is 2nd script, `e-prevent default` and `submit function`

If button disable after form submission and wants to enable it, you can use following piece of code inside validate plugin, so it will again enable the button once the fields will have all valid values.

```
onkeyup: function( element, event ) {
   this.checkForm();
    if (this.valid()) { // checks form for validity
        $('#theSubmitButton').attr("disabled", false); //Button enable if all fields valid
    } else {
        $('#theSubmitButton').attr("disabled", true); //button will disbale if any field not valid
    }
},
```

Edit:

OP added the form later so changes required in HTML

Move `<input class="submit2" type='button' id='submit' value='Send Message' />` inside the `<form></form>` and change `type='button'` to `type='submit'`

```
<form name='message' id='message' class="contactusform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=admin_url()?>admin-post.php">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
 echo $_SESSION['message'];
 unset($_SESSION['message']);
 }
?>
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
     <input type="hidden" name="data" value="foobarid">
     <label>Full Name:</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" value="" required="">
     <label>Phone Number:</label>
     <input type"=text" name="telno" id="telno">
     <label>Email Address:</label>
     <input type="email" name="email" value="" required="">
     <label>Town:</label>
     <input type"=text" name="town" value="" required="">
     <label>Device:</label>
     <select name="device" value="" required="">
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="Not Sure">Not Sure</option>
        ....Rest of the option attributes
        <option value="iPod Touch">iPod Touch</option>
    </select>
    <label>Message:</label><textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="4" value="" required=""></textarea>
    <input class="submit2" type='submit' id='submit' value='Send Message' />
</form>
<div id='simple-msg'></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z97rv5ju/2/)

Comment: I have removed my scripts and added your suggestion - it is not working - no validation is appearing - I checked the console - there is no errors which is good however I am missing something - any ideas what I need to change in order to get this working? I have added  added the updated code and the code for the form into my initial post.

Comment: Try to change the submit button type from button to  `submit`

Comment: Changed the type to submit and it still isn't working. When I click submit nothing happens.

Comment: now I had my cup coffee and here is it with your HTML and with `input type="submit"` http://jsfiddle.net/z97rv5ju/2/ will update the answer too.

Comment: Shehary - thanks for your help. The validation is working correctly and the sending confirmation - your message has been sent is appearing however the message is now not saving in the Wordpress Admin for some reason. Any ideas how to fix this? I have included all updated code in the original post.

Comment: I love to help you with that but not very familiar with wordpress and don't want to put you on wrong track by saying try this or try that, My suggestion, open new question, tag the question with `wordpress` and only put relevant code there, validation is working so you only need code of  `ajax method (full code) html form (short version not full code) and wordpress php code & function (which handles message and you think it is not working as it should)` and someone with experience of wordpress for sure will point you in right direction.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

before calling ajax, check whether your form is valid or not

update your code with this new code:

```
if($('.contactusform').valid()){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Thanks for your request - we will be in touch soon!</p>');

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Message failed to send. Please try again!</p>');
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: @Shehary and Dinanath Thakur - thanks for your suggestions - I tried both and I couldn't get either to work - tried both together including the submit handler etc. Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u post your form ?

Comment: No I can't - I must be doing something wrong. Could you try explain more what I've to include on top of your code - submit handler etc.

Comment: try this one:

`if($('.contactusform').valid()){
       $("#message").submit();
}`

Comment: Dinanath could you do me a favour and use my code from above and add your solution into it and post it in your answer as I am not sure what needs changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem, take note of the following:

1. Merge both of your scripts into one, as it is totally pointless to have them in different tags.
2. Use either the `ID` or the `className` of the form, however, the preferable is the `ID`. [for the answer I'm assuming that `.contactusform` and `#contactusform` refer to the same element in the DOM].
3. The second call to `.validate()` method is not needed (so has to be removed). [*it may override the first call of the `.validate()` method with the validation rule objects passed in.*]
4. > // grab the submits button ID. do not use  inside the form. Use a button instead outside the form.
   >   `$("#submit2").click(function()` ...

   -- Why not use a button with `type='button'` inside the form which will *prevent* the form from being submitted so that you can perform the AJAX call.

Now to register a handler on the `submit` event of the form, replace the last part of your code with the following:

```
$("#contactusform").submit(function(e) //Note the registration of the submit event on the form and NOT a button
    {
        var theForm = this;    // reference to the form that raised the event
        // add a loading image in place of your returning outcome
        $("#simple-msg").html("Sending...");

        // serialize/combine all submitted fields into an array
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();

        // set url based of action
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

        // set ajax parameters
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Thanks for your request - we will be in touch soon!</p>');

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                $("#simple-msg").html('<p>Message failed to send. Please try again!</p>');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action -- Is ok to be here, although changing the form submission button's type to `button` will do the same trick
        //e.unbind();   // Not necessary
    });

    //$("#message").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM --- No need for this again, not sure if '#message' is a form, but either way, by clicking the form submission button, you'll be triggering the submit event on the form.
});
```

5. To reset the form fields [`.reset()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp) method on the form in the success handler of your AJAX call:

   ```
   theForm.reset();
   $('#theSubmitButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // disable form submission when submission successfull.
   ```